# printing multidimensional array in a following order

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, arr

The array given below shows the number of different models of mobile phones sold by different companies, in a shop for a week of 2017. You have to find the total number of mobile phones sold irrespective of models for each companies on that period in below format. Array (SAMSUNG => 9341, XIAOMI => 4807, ...)

```
$mobiles_sold = array( 
        '1_DAY_2017' => array('SAMSUNG' => array(549, 199, 999),'XIAOMI' => array(199, 2999, 499)), 
        '2_DAY_2017' => array('SAMSUNG' => array(699, 999),'LENOVO' => array(280, 2550, 849)), 
        '3_DAY_2017' => array('OPPO' => array(500, 599),'SAMSUNG' => array(799)), 
        '4_DAY_2017' => array('SAMSUNG' => array(1299, 499, 799, 2500),'OPPO' => array(299, 349, 499)), 
        '5_DAY_2017' => array('XIAOMI' => array(500, 270, 340), 'VIVO' => array(4599, 299)),
        '6_DAY_2017' => array('VIVO' => array(240, 1899, 759, 530),'OPPO' => array(999)), 
        '7_DAY_2017' => array('OPPO' => array(300, 252, 1290), 'LENOVO' => array(570, 1300, 666)), );
```

Comment: This is a poor question

Answer (score 0):

Okay. :) You may print them to the console if...
You make a loop and print them to the console is that what you want?

```
for (i = 0, i < SamsungArray.Length, i++){
    Debug.Log(SamsungArray[i]);
    i = i + 1;
}
```

Comment: Ooh... Multidimensional... ;-; Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `foreach` loop and using [array_sum](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php):

```
$result = [];

foreach ($mobiles_sold as $day) {
    foreach ($day as $key => $value) {
        if (!array_key_exists($key, $result)) {
            $result[$key] = array_sum($value);
            continue;
        }
        $result[$key] += array_sum($value);
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/sWBZr)